# Baseline on badges from other accounts on profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When on the [accounts tab of a user profile](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts), the baseline of the text for badges doesn't quite align with all the others.

I.e:

[image: Different formatting with badges]

Or even more pronounced when a user doesn't have any badges on the other site:

[image: Different formatting without badges]

This could be by-design I suppose, however I think it would look nicer all on the same baseline.  When there are no badges it might be an idea to have some sort of placeholder: "-" or similar so it doesn't look too empty - e.g:

[image: Proposed Improvement]

Just in case it's strange rendering, I'm using Safari 5.1.2 on OSX Snow Leopard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed on all sites in the next full build - it's already [here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts).

Comment: Why did community lose all its rep on SharePoint and SU? Do you now reset it to 1 each day?

Comment: We're refactoring how rep is stored and the community user having rep was causing difficulties, since he takes ownership of content in certain situations.

Comment: Thanks. That little imp was a rep whore... :)